# Is there a way of opening a directory from a specific path using stdio.h and stdlib.h?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program in C which gets a path of a directory and does things with the files inside.
Is there any way of doing this without using `dirent.h` or `dir.h`?

Also, is there any function which opens a directory with a url such as `fopen` but that opens files with a url path?

Answer (score 3):

The C language does not have the notion of *directories* so there is no standard C way of using them.

The `<dirent.h>` thing is a POSIX API, so it should be available in any *nix OS. Other oses have other mechanisms to read the directory. For example, in Windows there is `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()`.

You could use a third party, OS agnostic library, of course, but it will use any of these APIs under the hood.

Comment: @Begginer: example of `opendir()`? Or an example of a third party library?

Comment: More interesting question (and answer) than I initially thought. I'm so used to nix's (and other consumer devices') hierarchical file systems that I forgot there may be other things out there. The *path* argument to `fopen` could be anything, like an URL or database location. Classical file systems are doomed anyway.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Indeed. I used to forgot also that `open()` is not a C standard function, until I had to do C in Windows. About `fopen(url)` take a look at [emscriptem](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

On modern Unix-like systems, the answer is No (even though you can open a directory for reading, you can't actually read from it).

If you go back far enough in history, the answer was 'sometimes'.  If you look at p183-4 of the second edition of K&R, you will see code reading a directory directly.  That simply does not work on current versions of Unix.

You might be able to open a directory for reading, but you can't then do anything more with it.

```
$ cat opendot.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(".", "r");
    if (fp != 0)
    {
        printf("OK\n");
        char buffer[256];
        size_t nbytes;
        if ((nbytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), fp)) > 0)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < nbytes; i++)
                printf("0x%.2X\n", buffer[i]);
        }
        else
            printf("Read failed\n");
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
        printf("Failed\n");
    return 0;
}
$ make opendot
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror opendot.c -o opendot
$ ./opendot
OK
Read failed
$
```

(Tested on Mac OS X 10.10.3 with GCC 5.1.0.)

You can use `open()` to open a directory for reading, primarily so you can use the file descriptor in operations such as [`fchdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchdir.html) and
[`openat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/openat.html).  The `fopen()` calls illustrated above use the `open()` function underneath.

But you can't actually read from the directory.